# Convert a variable to a byte array

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to convert a video into a byte array for upload.

```
var videoInput = new Uri("/uploadNewVideo;component/test.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
```

I am trying to upload the byte array as parameter to php:

```
string a = "TRIAL";
string url = "phpURL?";
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url + "&uploadedfile=" + bytearray + "&name=" + a));
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is your code not working? Do you get any error message at compile time or runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong method to download the video itself. Instead of `DownloadStringAsync`, you need to use [OpenReadAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadasync%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). That way you can access the incoming byte stream.

Also, FYI, you will not be able to concatenate a byte array and a string the way you do it.